# Clearing aoACDS cores

Tags: cloud, mpi, hpc, sungridengine

```
[abhishekb@hpc ~]$ qstat -g c
CLUSTER QUEUE                   CQLOAD   USED    RES  AVAIL  TOTAL aoACDS  cdsuE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
all.q                             0.76     20      0     40     60     20      0
gpu.q                             0.07      0      0     20     20      0      0
highpri.q                         0.40      0      0     16     16      0      0
unrestricted.q                    0.61      0      0      0     76      0     76
[abhishekb@hpc ~]$ qstat -f | awk '$6~/[aoACDS]/ && $3!~/\^[0]/'

queuename                      qtype resv/used/tot. load_avg arch          states
all.q@compute-0-1.local        BIP   0/20/20        44.87    linux-x64     a
unrestricted.q@compute-0-1.loc BIP   0/0/20         44.87    linux-x64     ad
```

Somehow, some of my jobs have entered the aoACDS state. How can I clear them
with `qdel`.

Comment: This is not a programming question. You should rather read through the SGE user and administrator manuals.

Comment: I can't find it in the user manual http://it.iiitd.edu.in/HPC_final_doc.pdf. Before I have tried to use `qdel ` always but somehow I don't why some of my jobs shows error and shifts to aoACDS and it also doesn't appear while doing `qstat`.

Comment: May `man qstat` be your guide. Also, `unrestricted.q@compute-0-1.local` is currently disabled.